# rSync, Assuming Destination Directory Permissions

Tags: rsync

Using rSync, is it possible to have all copied files and directories assume the owner, group, and permissions of the destination directory, whatever they might be?

I've played with the following options in various combinations to no avail.  Copied files continue to take their properties with them.

```
--owner
--no owner
--group
--no group
--perms
--no perms
--chmod=ugo=rwX
```

Clearly I just don't get it.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because as written there’s nothing indicating it’s about Apple products or services described in the [Help]

Comment: Apologies.  I clicked the wrong link.